# How to unpack and decode '@\x01\x01\x00'?

Tags: python

I am encountering the following output and I cannot really understand it.
Could you please advise what it is exactly? How to unpack it?

```
'@\x01\x01\x00'
```

It does not look to be purely binary or hexadecimal.
I would like to see the ASCII representation of it.

Comment: You have a string of bytes, where did it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a sequence of four bytes with the values 64, 1, 1, 0.

To interpret it, you need to know how it was encoded or what it is supposed to represent.

Generally, you can unpack binary data in Python with the `unpack` function in the `struct` module:

```
import struct

intval = struct.unpack('i', '@\x01\x01\x00')
shortvals = struct.unpack('hh', '@\x01\x01\x00')
```

The first `unpack` line would give you the value of your string interpreted as a 4-byte integer, which is the number 65856. The second one interprets the string as two 2-byte integers (320 and 1).

Comment: thanks! @fmarc could you please advise how "\300\010\034\032j\000\001\032j\000\\\032j6~\032\256Bh\032\256D\005\032\256Y\331\032\256\202\026" can be unpacked ?

Comment: @NikosSkalis: For that, you need information about how the data was stored. Only you know that, or whoever wrote this data.

Answer (score 2):

You have a string of bytes, if you print it you are seeing the the ascii output:

```
In [5]: s = '@\x01\x01\x00'


In [8]: print(list(bytearray(s)))
[64, 1, 1, 0]
```

If you call `chr` on each of the ints you will see exactly the same output, 64 in ascii is `@`, `1` is a *SOH* and `0` is a *NUL* , without more info like where it came from there is not much else that can be suggested.

Comment: thanks! but what is SOH ?

Comment: @NikosSkalis, *start of heading* http://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm